# Group by key and send values into list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have a simple address class like below:

```
public class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public List<int> NodeIds { get; set; }
}
```

and have populated a list of addresses like below:

```
List<Address> listOfAddresses = new List<Address> 
{
    new Address {AddressId=1, NodeIds=new List<int>{1}},
    new Address {AddressId=2, NodeIds=new List<int>{2}},
    new Address {AddressId=3, NodeIds=new List<int>{3}},
    new Address {AddressId=1, NodeIds=new List<int>{4}},
    new Address {AddressId=1, NodeIds=new List<int>{5}}
}
```

and I want to group by on AddressIds so the result list will have NodeIds that are essentially rolled up in case of duplicates like below:

```
listOfAddressesWithoutDupes = 
AddressId=1, NodeIds=List<int>{1,4,5},
AddressId=2, NodeIds=List<int>{2}},
AddressId=3, NodeIds=new List<int>{3}
```

so basically I am looking at a groupby function(or something else) that will get me above 
result

```
List<Address> listOfFilteredAddresses = listOfAddresses.GroupBy(x=>x.AddressId).Select(y=>new Address{AddressId=y.Key, NodeIds=?});
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
List<Address> listOfFilteredAddresses =
    listOfAddresses
    .GroupBy(x=>x.AddressId)
    .Select(y=>new Address{
        AddressId=y.Key
    ,   NodeIds=y.SelectMany(x=>x. NodeIds).ToList()
    });
```

This assumes that `NodeIds` in the `Address` are unique; if they are not, add `Distinct()` after `SelectMany`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a better way:

```
List<Address> listOfFilteredAddresses =
listOfAddresses
.GroupBy(a => a.AddressId)
.Select(g => new Address
{
    AddressId = g.Key,
    NodeIds = g.ToList()
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do by another approach as below

```
    var listOfFilteredAddresses = from e in listOfAddresses
                                  group e by e.AddressId into g 
                                  select new
                                 {
                                  AddressID=g.Key,
                                  NodeIDs=g.Select(x=>x.NodeIds).ToList()
                                 };
```